# Code example for Java 8 server transaction

Tags: java, transactions, jta

I want to update the DB and a server with some new data in one transaction.

I'm using java 8 and i was looking for Java transaction API.

I have found `JTA` but saw no code example. Can someone please link to one?

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883742/lightweight-java-transaction-management) and [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42750131/1065869)

but there were about DB transaction and had no code example.

I want to make the transaction at a higher lever than the DAL level

as it wraps the peer-server update as well.

```
private void updateDbAndServer() throws Exception {



        if (rulesUiRepository.updateRulesUiSnapshot(nonSplittedRulesSnapshot) == -1)
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot save ui snapshot in DB");

        Map<RuleConditionBl, RtRule> splittedMap = nonSplittedRulesSnapshot.toSplittedMap();
        anotherService.updateConfig(splittedMap);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Spring Transaction API is very easy to use and allows you to concentrate about your businesses logic. The API is used in a declarative form. Check [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) for more info.